# "How to fix Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 in React and express

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, multer

I tried to upload an image to a  local folder with multer and React.I expect to success upload an image. However, as chrome debugger said Failed load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) [http://localhost:3000/]
I guess my code send wrong format of data to a server side. I really appreciate if you give me a solution for this. I spend full of days to tackle this issue.

React

```
const TopPage = () => {
  const [imageState, setImageState] = useState({
    imageName: "",
    imageData: ""
  });

  const onChange = e => {

    setImageState({
      imageName: "lovelove" + Date.now(),
      imageData: e.target.files[0]
    });
  };

  const onClick = async () => {
    const { imageName, imageData } = imageState;
    console.log(imageName);
    console.log(imageData);

    const fd = new FormData();
    await fd.append("imageName", imageName);
    await fd.append("imageData", imageData);

    await axios.post("/", fd, (res, req) => console.log(res));

  };

  return (
    <div enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/" method="post">
      <input type="file" onChange={e => onChange(e)} />
      <button onClick={onClick}>Submit</button>
      <img src={imageState.defaultImage} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Server

```
router.post("/", upload.single("myFile"), (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.file);

  if (!req.file) return res.send("Please upload a file");
  const newImage = new Image({
    imageName: req.body.imageName,
    imageData: req.file.path
  });
  newImage
    .save()
    .then(result => {
      console.log(result);
      res.status(200).json({
        access: true,
        document: result
      });
    })
    .catch(err => next(err));
});
```

Comment: Does your req.body have the imageName? 500 errors usually occur when there is some JS error in the server code which hasn't been handled.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have already installed multer, If you see the following code

```
router.post("/", upload.single("myFile"), (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.file);
```

The `"myFile"` has to be the name of the formField coressponding to the file that is being passed, which in your case is `"imageData"`. Try replacing `"myFile"` with `"imageData"`.

Also set headers for the axios post request being made from react. The form attributes may not have effect on the manual http requests

```
var header = {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }

await axios.post("/", fd,{ headers : header });
```

Try and let me know if it works.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. However, it doesn't work. I still get the same error. I assume it is a client-side bug since I can get a response back when I use postman.